# Getting webcam to work in ekiga in Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, camera, ekiga

My webcam is working properly using other programs - `Camorama` , `Guvcview` and web browsers(`firefox` and `chrome`); `ekiga` recognizes my webcam too and it even turns on its indicator light but there is nothing but an empty window:

[image: http://pasteboard.co/2DL9UBwI.png]

I played with camera settings in `ekiga` but no luck; also tried ekiga's debug option, yet nothing related showed up.

While opening camera with `ekiga`, `dmesg` gives me the bolded text:

**[Apr18 00:52] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 2).**

`dmesg` output:

```
[Apr18 00:50] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:02d2)
[  +0.001849] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6/4-1.6:1.0/input/input14
[  +0.000065] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  +0.000003] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[Apr18 00:51] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ +10.744755] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:02d2)
[  +0.001819] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6/4-1.6:1.0/input/input15
[  +0.000069] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  +0.000002] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[Apr18 00:52] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 2).
```

**lsusb output**

```
# lsusb -v -d 5986:02d2 

Bus 004 Device 003: ID 5986:02d2 Acer, Inc
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x5986 Acer, Inc
  idProduct          0x02d2
  bcdDevice            0.07
  iManufacturer           1 Ricoh Company Ltd.
  iProduct                2 Integrated Camera
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          794
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0
      iFunction               4 Integrated Camera
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              4 Integrated Camera
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength          104
        dwClockFrequency       30.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          5
        iTerminal               0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00040a0e
          Auto-Exposure Mode
          Auto-Exposure Priority
          Exposure Time (Absolute)
          Zoom (Absolute)
          PanTilt (Absolute)
          Privacy
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000157f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0
        bmVideoStandards     0x1b
          None
          NTSC - 525/60
          SECAM - 625/50
          NTSC - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                27
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 3
        guidExtensionCode         {0a3e1874-8254-1a48-b402-48b8b8c49cc8}
        bNumControl            12
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        bmControls( 1)       0x0f
        iExtension              0
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {ed2a1c0b-f739-d145-8100-fbcfac7ace06}
        bNumControl             6
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x3f
        iExtension              0
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             5
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            15
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         2
        wTotalLength                      563
        bEndPointAddress                  130
        bmInfo                              1
        bTerminalLink                       5
        bStillCaptureMethod                 1
        bTriggerSupport                     0
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                    27
        bmaControls( 1)                    27
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                8
        guidFormat                            {59555932-0000-1000-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x02
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 1 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
          bCopyProtect                      0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                 73728000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           360
        dwMinBitRate                 55296000
        dwMaxBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        dwMinBitRate                 24330240
        dwMaxBitRate                 48660480
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      202752
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 18432000
        dwMaxBitRate                 36864000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            800
        wHeight                           448
        dwMinBitRate                 86016000
        dwMaxBitRate                 86016000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      716800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         666666
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         6
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            960
        wHeight                           540
        dwMinBitRate                 82944000
        dwMaxBitRate                 82944000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1036800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1000000
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         7
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1000000
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         8
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            424
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 24422400
        dwMaxBitRate                 48844800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      203520
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            11
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  6 (FORMAT_MJPEG)
        bFormatIndex                        2
        bNumFrameDescriptors                7
        bFlags                              0
          Fixed-size samples: No
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x02
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
          bCopyProtect                      0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxBitRate                221184000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      921600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           360
        dwMinBitRate                 82944000
        dwMaxBitRate                165888000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      691200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        dwMinBitRate                 36495360
        dwMaxBitRate                 72990720
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      304128
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 27648000
        dwMaxBitRate                 55296000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      230400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            800
        wHeight                           448
        dwMinBitRate                129024000
        dwMaxBitRate                258048000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1075200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         6
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                            960
        wHeight                           540
        dwMinBitRate                186624000
        dwMaxBitRate                373248000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1555200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         7
        bmCapabilities                   0x01
          Still image supported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                331776000
        dwMaxBitRate                663552000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     2764800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            666666
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0b5c  2x 860 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x135c  3x 860 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13c0  3x 960 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13fc  3x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

What is the problem? What can I do to make `ekiga` work with my webcam?

Comment: Trying to add this issue to my tutorial on http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_web_cam. So your webcam works perfectly everywhere but in ekiga, right?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk Staerk Yes it works perfectly everywhere except in ekiga

Comment: I just figured out webcam/ekiga problem are not related to the dmesg message just tested ekiga on debian and it worked great with the same message from dmesg I think its related to ekiga or some other packages but I don't know how to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: we need to understand exactly what you are doing. Call ekiga, click on the camera symbol, right?

Comment: btw I never could solve any problem I have with ekiga, could you?